# How to disable MailChimp double opt-in?

Tags: php, html, email, mailchimp

I am trying to disable MailChimp double opt-in in the HTML form.

I found some solutions but they are for the old API (1 and 2).
Now mailchimp is use API 3. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a MailChimp signup form, you cannot disable double opt-in.

If you're using API v3, you can avoid double opt-in by setting the subscriber's status to 'subscribed' as described here: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/